# Trace minimization with column norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, qcqp

For a symmetric and **negative** semidefinite matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, how can one solve the following QCQP in tall matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \text{Trace}(X^\top Q X)\\ \text{subject to} &  \left\| x_i \right\|_2^2 \leq 1, \quad \forall i \in [r]\end{array}$$

where $x_i$ is the $i$-th column of $X$? Generally, $n \gg r$.

Comment: Do you have a constraint on the width of the allowed matrix $X$? Otherwise this quantity is unbounded I believe.

Comment: @paulinho The problem is not unbounded due to the column norm constraint.

Comment: The question would be more interesting if $X$ needed to have full column rank.

Comment: Can't you just have as many columns as you want in $X$? You specified that $X$ could be rectangular, so by just including the same column over and over again, you could get this sum to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this trace is simply equal to $\sum_{i}x_i^TQx_i$. Thus, it suffices to separately minimize $x_i^TQx_i$ over the columns of $x_i$. By the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, this minimum is attained if and only if $x_i$ is a unit eigenvector associated with the smallest (i.e. largest in absolute value) eigenvalue of $Q$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to derive a similar relationship if the norm constraint is on the rows (not columns) of X?

Comment: @w382903 I don't see a nice way to do so

Comment: Thanks! I opened this as a new question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845885/trace-minimization-with-row-norm-constraint